# Who are Mike, Esther, and Sheila?

Tags: riddle

[My recent riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15823/our-reply-to-your-accusations-who-are-we) was a bit too lengthy for some, so I tried to keep this one short:

---

While Esther cares for many people,
Her best friend, Mike, just runs around,
Never providing much for anyone.

Mike loves Esther,
Only showing her his good side, but
He has a side that she has never seen!

They both love their friend, Sheila.
She is very generous to them, and
She knows both of Mike's sides very well.

They all usually get along great,
But sometimes Esther gets jealous,
And prevents Mike from seeing Sheila.

Sometimes Mike gets angry at Esther
And tries to keep her from seeing Sheila,
But he never fully succeeds.

---

**Who are Mike, Esther, and Sheila?**

Comment: "He has a side that she has never seen!" This is almost certainly inaccurate. It is *very* unlikely that the non-good side of Mike was never shown to Esther from the time they met. As of now, Mike never shows Esther his other side, but he probably only gradually chose to keep one side hidden.

Comment: Too technical for the riddle, perhaps. My issue is that it is very likely that all sides have already been seen, not that they will be seen in the future. It takes time to achieve the state of showing only one side. Other than creationism, there are no models/theories which have Mike and Esther reach their current state without all sides having been shown in the past. It would be easy to re-word such that the riddle is present/future tense instead of that it *has never* happened (in the past) (e.g. "that she never sees").

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Mike, Esther and Sheila are...

> ... the Moon, Earth and Sun.

Esther cares for many people,

> There are many people on the Earth.

Her best friend, Mike, just runs around,
Never providing much for anyone.

> The Moon orbits the Earth and no one lives on it.

Mike loves Esther,
Only showing her his good side, but
He has a side that she has never seen!

> One side of the Moon faces the Earth all the time.

They both love their friend, Sheila.
She is very generous to them, and
She knows both of Mike's sides very well.

> The Earth and Moon orbit the Sun as a unit, and the Sun 'sees' both sides of the Moon.  The Sun is generous in providing light/heat to the Earth and Moon.

The final two stanzas:

> These refer to solar and lunar eclipses.

Comment: Nice one! I was about to answer the same, but you were fast!

Comment: +1 Good job. I am glad a new person got it! I knew it wouldn't last long, although I still think it's a good one.

Comment: I'm in agreement on the answer. Nice riddle - I like ones that make you think but aren't *too* hard :)